# How to make a website work with and without javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

For several reasons (e.g. noscript browser plugins), for my current project, I'm trying to make a website work without client-side javascript. But for the cases where javascript can create an added value (e.g. foldable content), I'd provide it. So a user with js turned off will see an uglier page but will have access to everything.

Therefore, in the html I can't use any class that would e.g. hide an element which would later be modified by js. So my attempt (code snippet 1) was to first show everything and then via js add the classes to the elements I want to manipulate. This works, but because the js takes some time to load and some extra time to work, there is a short glitch when loading the page, so you basically see how js is hiding the previously shown elements.
So I was wondering if that's something I'll have to live with or if there's a workaround? Maybe something with the  tag? E.g. a style tag inside a noscript tag, which would override the hiding classes (code snippet 2)?

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="head">
        Topic 1 <button>+</button>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        abc
    </div>
<div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="head">
        Topic 2 <button>+</button>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        abc
    </div>
<div>
```

```
document.querySelectorAll(".container").forEach(el => {el.classList.add("contentHidden")});
```

------------ OR ------------

```html
<noscript>
    <style>
        .container.contentHidden>content {
            display: initial;
        }
    </style>
</noscript>

<div class="container contentHidden">
    <div class="head">
        Topic 1 <button>+</button>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        abc
    </div>
<div>

<div class="container contentHidden">
    <div class="head">
        Topic 2 <button>+</button>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        abc
    </div>
<div>
```

Comment: Note that anyone running with js disabled is used to sites not working as expected since not many sites will provide a fallback and js runs so much these days. But also note the js shown will not be supported in some browsers.. arrow functions, classList, NodeList.forEach etc

Comment: @charlietfl Thank you for your evaluation. The untrusty browser support is another reason why I want to make it basically work without js. That way I could use things like forEach just as it suits best and when a browser doesn't support it, the user would just see the fallback solution. This of course wouldn't work well with the <noscript> solution I guess, because js *is* enabled.

Comment: But you can write js so it is cross browser supported when js is enabled. Or transpile it and add polyfills. There is a difference between supported methods and js disabled ... former can throw errors ...latter just won't run it

Comment: @charlietfl that's what I was trying to say, but thanks for clarifying

Comment: A big bold message in a `<noscript>` that says something like *"you need js enabled"* is typically sufficient in modern web. Unless you have some very specific edge case

Comment: I’ve also been searching for a solution to this but I think it’s something we have to live with for people who disable JS. I typically hide the elements once the DOM has loaded. I guess the only way to hide the “judder” effect would be to add a full screen pre-loader which hides when the page has finished loading. I’m personally not a fan of pre-loaders though. Only other option from my knowledge would be to prevent them from accessing the site if JS is disabled as mentioned above, that’s what I do now on projects.

Comment: @Matt thank you for sharing your experience. What bums me out about the "judder", pre-loader etc. things is that it will affect the "regular" users who have js turned on and fully functional. For the users with noscript or bad browsers I'd find it ok to have some negative effects, but this way the js-users have to pay for the noscript-users

Answer (score 0):

How about using a CSS animation which hides the element

```
@keyframes hidefirst {
    from {visibilty: hidden;}
    to {visibilty: visible;}
}
.hide {
    animation-name: hidefirst;
    animation-duration: 10000ms;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
} 
.permhide {
    visibilty: hidden;
}
```

Then use Javascript to update from the temporary hidden class to permanently hidden class.

let hidden = document.getElementsByClassName('hide');

```
hidden. foreach(
    element => element.className = 'permhide' )
```

Comment: That's a very interesting approach. Have you used it yourself or seen it somewhere, or is it just an idea?

Comment: Just an idea. Your question got me thinking and it was the only option I could come up with.